# Помогите найти ошибку в коде Python с input()

Tags: python

```
print("Выберите вид фундамента:")
print("1. Свайно-винтовой")
print("2. Блоки 20")
print("3. Блоки 200")
print("4. Плиты дорожные")
print("5. Плиты")
found = input()
print("Сколько блоков фундамента Вы берёте?")
quan = int(input())
if found == 1:
    print(1000 * quan)
elif found == 2:
    print(2000 * quan)
elif found == 3:
    print(2200 * quan)
elif found == 4:
    print(750 * quan)
else:
    print(500 * quan)
```

Comment: input() по умолчанию не даёт число.

Answer (score 5):

Дело в том,  `found = input()` возвращает строку,т.к. функция input() всегда вернёт строку,а не число и далее при проверке `if found == 1` ни один if не срабатывает. 
**Вам следует написать `found = int(input())`** , если вы точно знаете, что пользователь введёт число.

Также, в качестве альтернативы, можете делать проверку так:

```
if found == "1":
    print(1000 * quan)
elif found == "2":
    print(2000 * quan)
elif found == "3":
    print(2200 * quan)
elif found == "4":
    print(750 * quan)
else:
    print(500 * quan)
```

Более того, переменные лучше называть более говорящими именами и делать проверку ввода данных от пользователя, ну вот хотябы так:

```
found_type = input()
if( not(found_type.isdigit()) or (int(found_type)<1) or (int(found_type)>5) ):
    print("Неверные данные!")
    exit()
```